# Why isn't the apostrophe on the 'front page' of mobile virtual keyboards?

Tags: keyboard

In terms of punctuation marks the apostrophe, must be used almost as much as commas or full stops.  Yet it doesn't get a front screen ( single press ) on either of the mobile keyboards I have loaded (GBoard and Grammarly).

Why ?

Comment: Possibly because auto-correct/-suggest will turn `doesnt` into `doesn't` sufficiently well for the (seemingly diminishing) number of people who still care about punctuation?

Comment: Maybe the diminishing number is being caused by auto-correct not being fully used ???